CSS Grid: Creating Overlapping Grid Items with Different Z-Indexes
I am working on a layout using CSS Grid where I need two grid items to overlap each other. The overlapping elements should have different z-index values to control which one appears on top. However, when I apply z-index values to the overlapping grid items, the z-index property doesn’t seem to have any effect. Both items remain at the same stacking level.
I created a CSS Grid container and defined a grid with specific rows and columns. I positioned the two items to overlap by placing them in the same grid area. Then, I tried to apply z-index to each item to control their stacking order, but the z-index doesn’t seem to change their positioning as expected.
See my code down:


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 200px);
  gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  background-color: coral;
  z-index: 2;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
</div>




the z-index property doesn’t seem to have any effect. --> because items2 is already on the top following the default order so making its z-index bigger won't change nothing

What overlap are you wanting? Currently both items are in the same grid cells and the coral one is over the top of the first one.

You can use order to modify the stack order, no need of position to trigger z-index ;) ex: `.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 200px);
gap: 10px;
}
.item1 {
grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
background-color: lightblue;
order: 1;
}
.item2 {
grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
background-color: coral;
}`  and the blue one shows over the coral one
